# FFmpeg calculating PSNR on MPTS files

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 MPTS files with the same pid 3511. first file base, second after transcoder. I want to calculte PSNR between it.

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i origin.ts -i ref.ts -streamid 0:3511 -streamid 1:3511 -lavfi psnr=stats_file=psnr_logfile.txt -f null -
```

but ffmpeg return me an error:

```
    [Parsed_psnr_0 @ 000002161e3c6a40] Width and height of input videos must be same.
[Parsed_psnr_0 @ 000002161e3c6a40] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_psnr_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:2
```

Is it posible to select the same pid from first and second streams and calculate PSNR?

Comment: Show the complete log.

Comment: @llogan can't post all logs here When i try to post it sites give me an error: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Could be a formatting issue. You can get that error if **all** of the text in your question was formatted as code.